# Xamarin Access to contact book to get informations

Tags: android, xamarin, contacts

I am working on an application on Android (Xamarin) and here's what I want to do :

When the user click on a button, he can select a contact in the contact book and then the name and the phone number are written in 2 editText (name and phone Number)

how can I do to access the contact book and to get the data I need ?

here's my code right now :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Preferences;
using Android.Provider;

namespace EmergencyCall
{
    [Activity(Label = "AddContact")]
    public class AddContact : Activity
    {
        EditText nom;
        EditText numero;
        Button save;
        Button addFromReper;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.add_Contact);
            nom = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.nomPersonne);
            numero = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.NumeroTel);
            save = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.saveNewContact);
            addFromReper = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.addFromRepert);
            ISharedPreferences prefs;
            ISharedPreferencesEditor editor;
            prefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(ApplicationContext);
            editor = prefs.Edit();


            save.Click += delegate
            {
                ISet<String> names = new HashSet<String>    (prefs.GetStringSet("NomsContacts", new HashSet<String>()));
                names.Add(nom.Text);
                editor.PutStringSet("NomsContacts", names);
                editor.PutString(nom.Text, numero.Text);
                editor.Apply();
                StartActivity(typeof(ModifyContacts));
            };

            addFromReper.Click += delegate
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionPick,     Contacts.ContentUri);
                StartActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            };

        }

    }
}
```

Thank you :)

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/data/contentproviders/read_contacts/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If someone needs it, I finally found how to do it :**

```
 protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 1)
        {

            if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
            {
                Android.Net.Uri contactData = data.Data;
                ICursor cursor = ContentResolver.Query(contactData, null, null, null, null);

                cursor.MoveToFirst();
                string name = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.DisplayName));
                string number = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(Android.Provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.Number));

                nom.Text=name;
                numero.Text = number;

            }
        }
```